# Redimension de un conjunto de campos en un conjunto de tablas por medio de un bucle .NET

Tags: vb.net, .net, ms-access

Tengo dos vectores con datos String

```
Public tablas() As String = {"LinFraVen", "LinAlbVen", "LinPedCli", "LinPres", "LinFraCom", "LinAlbCom", "LinPedPro", "LinInven", "LinTarifa", "NecesidadProductos", "LinCuotas", "LinActob", "LinOrdCom", "LinOrdSeg", "DenominacionesAmpliadas", "Etiquetas"}
Public campos() As String = {"descripción", "descripción", "descripción", "descripción", "descripción", "descripción", "descripción", "descripción", "descripción", "descripción", "denominacion", "descripción", "descripción", "DenominacionAmpliada", "denominacion"}
```

Tengo que redimensionar los campos a (100 TEXT)
Por ejemplo:

```
LinFraVen campo descripcion 
LinAlbVen campo descripcion 
DenominacionesAmpliadas campo DenominacionAmpliada
```

El codigo para redimensionar seria este

```
cmdOledb = New OleDbCommand("ALTER TABLE productos ALTER COLUMN Denominacion TEXT(50)", conexion)
```

Como podria recorrer con un bucle e ir redimensionando los campos, de de la siguiente manera. 
Posicion 1 dentro de tablas  su campo es la posicion 1 dentro de campos, y asi sucesivamente. 
Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo debes comparar que los índices coincidan entre los arreglos y aplicar una instrucción [break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-cl/library/37zc9d2w.aspx) en caso de hacerlo.

Algo así:

```
List<string> v1 = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
List<string> v2 = new List<string> { "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco" };

            for(int i = 0; i < v1.Count; i++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < v2.Count; x++)
                {
                    if(x == i)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(v1[i] + "/" + v2[x]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar ArrayList o mejor aún la clase StringCollection.
Entonces puedes redimensionar tu colección:

```html
Dim myCol As New StringCollection()
//Agrega los elementos al final de la colección
myCol.Add("columna1")
myCol.Add("columnaN")

//Agrega los elementos en el índice que necesites
//myCol.Insert(indice, texto)
myCol.Insert(1, "columna2")
```